# Is it possible to send a list of complex element with in a complex element in c#?

Tags: c#

In my web service I have to pass list of complex elements in a complex element.

my first  class is:

```
public List<JBCredential> JBCredentials{ get; set; }
public string codes { get; set; }
public string db { get; set; }
public string locale { get; set; }
public string location { get; set; }
public string mode { get; set; }
public string postcode { get; set; }
```

In the above class I've to send list of another class as below:

```
public string code { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Now I want to send the above class to my method.
But when I'm adding the second class to list of first class, I'm getting the following error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

I've tried the following

```
     test.request s=new test.request();
     test.JBCredential jb = new test.JBCredential();
        jb.code = "LNK";
        jb.Username = "";
        jb.Password = "";
        /
        s.query = "java";

        s.mode = "mock_search";
        s.JBCredentials.Add(jb);//I'm not getting add method

          so I've tried like this
        s.JBCredentials[0].code = jb.code;
        s.JBCredentials[0].Password = jb.Password;
        s.JBCredentials[0].Username = jb.Username;
and also I tried
List<JBCredential> ad=new List<JBCredential>();
  ad.Add(jb);
 s.JBCredentials=ad;
```

I am able to pass values to JBcredentials type  from normal request but I 'm unable to pass this type when I'm invoking the web service.

Comment: pls show how you're doing add and other code

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you initialize your list in your constructor:

```
public ComplexClass {
  public ComplexClass() {
    this.JBCredentials = new List<JBCredential>();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've initialized that one in my constructor

Comment: Are you sure? NREs with lists usually mean they have not been properly initialized.